# Проблемы с подключением ncurses в netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ncurses

Добавил в опции компилятора `c++` опцию `-lncurses`. При сборке выдается следующая ошибка:

> cd '/home/ilia/NetBeansProjects/Console' /usr/bin/make -f Makefile
>   CONF=Debug "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=
>   SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf make[1]: Вход в каталог
>   `/home/ilia/NetBeansProjects/Console' "/usr/bin/make"  -f
>   nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/console make[2]: Вход
>   в каталог`/home/ilia/NetBeansProjects/Console' mkdir -p
>   build/Debug/GNU-Linux rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" g++
>   -lncurses   -c -g -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o
>   main.cpp g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++14’
>   make[2]: ***  [build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o] Ошибка 1 make[2]: Выход из
>   каталога `/home/ilia/NetBeansProjects/Console' make[1]: ***
>   [.build-conf] Ошибка 2 make[1]: Выход из каталога`
>   /home/ilia/NetBeansProjects/Console' make: *** [.build-impl] Ошибка 2
>
> СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 58ms)

Comment: `gcc --version` что говорит?

Comment: @pink gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: `g++` то есть, не gcc.

Comment: да, вот выхлоп `g++ --version` g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Отдельно через `g++ *.cpp -o prog -lncurses` компилится нормально

Comment: Так тут вы не указываете `-std=c++14`, поэтому и компилится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`G++-4.8.x` не поддерживает C++14
Вам нужно выбрать другой стандарт `C++`
Для этого идете в меню `Файл-Свойства-Компилятор С++`
В сроке `C++ Standard` выбираете `C++11` или `C++98`

Comment: Та же балалайка

Comment: Ошибки теперь только вроде `/home/ilia/NetBeansProjects/Console/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `initscr'
/home/ilia/NetBeansProjects/Console/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/ilia/NetBeansProjects/Console/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `wmove'
/home/ilia/NetBeansProjects/Console/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `stdscr'`

Answer (score 1):

[Поддержка C++14 разными версиями g++](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14). Как следует из таблицы **C++14 Language Features**, относительно полноценная поддержка этого стандарта начинается с версий 4.9, а совсем полноценная - с версий 5.x (хотя по умолчанию режим `-std=c++14` включается аж в версии 6.1).

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Я добавлял `-lncurses` в опции компилятора, а надо в опции линкера. Спасибо всем, что подсказали поменять стандарт. На `11` все заработало!